# insert values from 2 textbox in one column

Tags: c#, mysql

> the problem is when I clicked the save button where this code is... it says that Parameter '@email' has already been defined... and what i want to happen is to insert these values in one column(email) but not in the same row

```
string[] email = new string[2];
email[0] = txtEmail1.Text;
email[1] = txtEmail2.Text;

MySqlCommand cmd;

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO email(Id,email)VALUES( @Id,@email)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", int.Parse(txtId.Text));

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email[i]);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (i==2)
        break;
}
```

Comment: you insert two email in column with one id you cannt do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear the parameters in each iteration of the loop.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO email (Id,email) VALUES ( @Id, @email )";

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", int.Parse(txtId.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email[i]);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```